# Bottom Border CSS Transition not Stretching across

Tags: css

Playing some more with pseudo elements and I wanted to simulate the bottom border of a list-item element growing from the left on a hover over.  Unfortunately, I can manage to get the line to grow the length of the text, just not the length of the border of the full list item.

I've put a border on the list items so you know what I mean

HTML:

```
<div id="orangeNavBar">
<ul>
    <li>Home</li>
    <li>Products</li>
    <li>Company</li>
    <li>Contact</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body
{
margin: 0;
}

*
{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

#orangeNavBar
{
height: 45px;
width: 627px;
background-color: #E87966;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
margin-top: 15px;
}

ul
{
list-style:none;
}

ul li
{
float: left;
display: inline-block;
font-family: verdana;
font-size: .9em;
font-weight: bold;
color: white;
height: 45px;
box-sizing: border-box;
padding: 13.5px 20px;
transition: color .3s;
border: 1px solid black;

}

ul li::after
{
display: block;
content: "";
background: black;
height: 2px;
width: 0px;
transition: width 0.2s ease;
} 

ul li:hover::after
{
width: 100%;
}

ul li:hover
{
color: black;
}
```

[Link to Codepen](http://codepen.io/theodore_steiner/pen/vKpLrN)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add the following CSS, it should work as you expect:

```
ul li {
    position: relative;
}

ul li:after {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

The `position: relative` is required to make sure the pseudo element is constrained by the width and height of the `<li>` instead of the entire `<body>`.

The `position: absolute;` for the pseudo element allows you to anchor the element to the bottom left (`bottom: 0; left: 0;`) of the `<li>` element.

Answer (score 0):

1. You should wrap the text with  tag.
2. Then assign `position:relative` to it and move the `::after` values of `li` to `span`. **so that the border-bottom applies under the text only .**
3. And have to alter few css properties to perfect the alignment .

Here is my working [codepen](http://codepen.io/vishnu1212/pen/ZOvJrR) snippet of your project

**HTML:**

```
<ul>
    <li><span>Home</span></li>
    <li><span>Products</span></li>
    <li><span>Company</span></li>
    <li><span>Contact</span></li>
</ul>
```

**CSS:**

```
ul li span {
    display:block;
    padding: 13.5px 0;
    position: relative;
}
ul li span::after {
    display: block;
    content: "";
    background: black;
    height: 3px;
    width: 0px;
    transition: width 0.2s ease;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}
ul li:nth-child(n+1)::before {
    top: 20px;
}
ul li:hover span::after {
    width: 100%;
}
```